# SQL como iterar apenas por duas colunas para cada usuário distinto?

Tags: sql

Suponha que possua a seguinte tabela:

| Usuarios | Data | Compra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pedro | 10-10-21 | 11,59 |
| Pedro | 11-10-21 | 21,00 |
| Pedro | 12-10-21 | 5,99 |
| Maria | 09-10-21 | 18,01 |
| Maria | 10-10-21 | 1.010,10 |
| Maria | 11-10-21 | 58,00 |
| Maria | 12-10-21 | 73,89 |
| Jose | 21-10-21 | 100,00 |

Como faço para gerar uma tabela com apenas as 2 primeiras compras de cada usuário no mês? A tabela que gostaria apresentaria os resultado assim:

| Usuarios | Data | Compra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pedro | 10-10-21 | 11,59 |
| Pedro | 11-10-21 | 21,00 |
| Maria | 09-10-21 | 18.01 |
| Maria | 10-10-21 | 1.010,10 |
| Jose | 21-10-21 | 100,00 |

Sou iniciante em SQL, sei que não existe for each na linguagem, então como eu busco um usuário, pego o valor das duas primeiras compras no mês desse usuário e vou para o próximo e repito o processo até o último usuário?

O que eu tentei:

```
SELECT Usuarios, Compra, Data  
FROM Tabela
LIMIT 2;
```

Mas isso limita o número total de colunas, e não de usuário a usuário. Como obter o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce pode utilizar a função ROW_NUMBER que retorna o número sequencial de uma linha dentro de uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, começando em 1 para a primeira linha em cada partição.

Segue o exemplo:

```
select
t.USUARIOS,
t.DATA,
t.COMPRA
from
(
    select
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.usuarios ORDER BY  t.data, t.compra asc) 
      AS Row  
    from
    Tabela t
) t 
where
t.Row <= 2
order by
t.data
```